# Help with JavaScript replace

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var isbn = '978-0393317558';
alert(isbn.replace(/^[^0-9]+/, '')); //this gives the same value
```

Why isn't that dash being replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the first `^` forces the match to be at the beginning of the string.